# Using a single macro on several tables across several sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook that is split one page=one month of the year.
on each of those sheets is a table with various conditional formatting on it.
from there I filter the information several ways to obtain certain bits of information, (outstanding balances, items waiting for dispatch etc etc)

I am trying to set up some simple macros to make filtering quicker, e.g show only orders from a particular company, that have been dispatched, but not paid for.

My problem is, the macro only applies to the sheet/table I created it on, is it possible to reword the vb code to make the macro work across all sheets/tables of my work book?

This is an example of one of the macros, sorry if there is protocol for inserting code on this forum, I plead ignorance.

```
Sub HSWC_only()
'
' HSWC_only Macro
' leaves only hi-spec jobs
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+m
'
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table25").Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:= _
        "=HSWC*", Operator:=xlAnd
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The key you are looking for is the `ActiveSheet`, this now applies the Autofilter only to the sheet you see in front of you. If you would change that you an object that you can link to each sheet you could apply it to each sheet in order.

Now when your sheets all have only one List you could reference the 1st ListObject in stead of its name.

If you would put the line in a `Loop` like this:

```
Sub HSWC_only() 
'
'HSWC_only Macro 
' leaves only hi-spec jobs 
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+m
'
    Dim ws as Worksheet

    For each ws in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.ListObjects(1).Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:= _ 
            "=HSWC*", Operator:=xlAnd 
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time..
I pasted the code you suggested, but then I find that the macro doesn't work at all, and comes up with a 'runtime error 9-supscript out of range'
which is the same error it was bringing up on sheets other than the sheet where the macro was created before I messed with it.

Comment: if it has no list objects it brings up errors about data ranges :(

Comment: Well if there are sheets without object lists then aparently all sheets do NOT look the same... Different premises require different approaches. Do you manually create the table first? Then you can record that as a macro as well and put those lines (with similar modification) in this script. So 1) Create table 2) Apply the filter.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your macro should do that since it refers to `ActiveSheet`, so it should work on any sheet you're currently in.

If it doesn't it's because of the `ListObjects("Table25").Range` reference - You might want to change that to something along the lines of `UsedRange`

Your code would look something along the lines of:

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:= _
    "=HSWC*", Operator:=xlAnd
```

Without seeing your sheets / layout, that's the closest I can offer to a solution.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi,

thanks for taking the time to help me out :)
unfortunately it didn't work..
before, when I tried to run the macro on a different sheet it came back with 'run time error 9-subscript out of range'
after making the edit you suggested it didn't work at all, and came back with 'error 1004 autofilter method out of range class failed'

Comment: **HOPING** you only have one table per page - Try `ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Range.Autofilter ...`